# Disabling overridden materializations from imported dbt package

Tags: dbt

I'm importing an internal dbt package that has overridden some built-in materializations (i.e. `view`, `table`, and `incremental`). I'd like to use some models and macros from this package while disabling these custom implementations of the built-in materializations. Currently, they're overriding the built-ins for both the imported package's models *and* those in my root project.

I've tried specifying a [dispatch config](https://docs.getdbt.com/reference/dbt-jinja-functions/dispatch) in my root project to give priority to the default materializations in the global namespace with no luck:

```
dispatch:
  - macro_namespace: my_project
    search_order: ['dbt', 'my_project']
  - macro_namespace: custom_package
    search_order: ['dbt', 'my_project']
```

Other alternatives I've considered:

- Updating the list of `macro-paths` in the custom package's config to exclude the `macros/materializations/` folder based on a variable defined in the root project
- A significant refactor the imported package to not override these materializations, and maybe hand-copying the built-in materializations into my project's `macros/materializations/` directory in the meantime
- Forgoing dbt's packaging system and importing these models another way (e.g. a git submodule)

Is there a way to disable/exclude these materializations in the root project?

Comment: In your dbt package, are there any other built-in macros being overriden? Or the materializations are the only ones?

Comment: @AleixCC Just `generate_schema_name`. And I do have the flexibility do reorganize the `macros/` directory in the custom package to selectively enable/disable macros by path.

Comment: And you want to always use dbt's built-in functions instead of the ones defined in your `custom_package`?

Comment: More specifically I want to always use dbt’s built-in materializations

Comment: In that case, I would follow the suggestion from these dbt docs, and just use a different naming (e.g. adding a prefix/suffix) to define your custom materialisation: https://docs.getdbt.com/guides/advanced/creating-new-materializations